# figure margins STILL too large even after minimizing in R

Tags: r, plot, margins

I want to classify individuals into clusters using model based hierarchical agglomerative clustering via the R package "mclust".

I have 1229 observations (i.e. individuals) and 65 variables (i.e. SNPs).

I ran the function Mclust() successfully but am having a difficult time plotting the results. 
I can plot "BIC" successfully but when I plot "classification", "density", and "uncertainty", R returns "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large".

I shrank the margin sizes from

$mar
[1] 4.5 2.5 2.5 1.5

to

$mar
[1] 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05

and continue to get the same error message.

Are there other methods that can circumvent this issue?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.